# Only group some rows on Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I'm looking at row grouping with Ag-Grid and have got it working in my project (grouping art works by master edition, with child elements being editions). The problem is that some art works are not master editions, nor editions. They're just their own work without being a part of a set.

Right now Ag-Grid creates a group for every single art work. So, those of type "normal" have a "normal" group, etc. I only want grouping behaviour on works of type "master edition". Is there a proper way to do this?

My current idea was to create a custom cell renderer that only renders HTML if `params.node.group = true`. This feels pretty hacky though so I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your problem, a tree view could help you:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/

You could accomplish that asymetric grouping, by creating a tree path dynamically, in the getDataPath callback in gridOptions.

```
getDataPath: function(data) {
    return data.type === "master edition" ? ["master edition", data.name]: [data.name];
}
```

Plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/3jdzvQ1QJmF7xJy1

Comment: Ended up using the master/detail feature instead and embedding a new grid. Works well and I get to have more flexibility with further sorting/filtering of child elements which is great. I'll put you down as the answer though because a tree view would have probably worked too. Thanks!